# Unit testing of base class with jasmine and angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have one generic base class that I uses in each grid component.

Now, I have specs for grid component but I want to add specs for base class in separate base spec file.

Motive behind that is to remove repetitive code and make generic spec file for base grid which will be served for each grid that used base class.

I stuck at one point, **I am not able to create a specs inside base spec file. Basically I want all the specs in base file under one function, and when this function called from sub class with that component, it should return all the specs for that class.**

> Here is what I have and what I tried so far.

**Component Layer:**

```
export class MyComponent extends BaseGrid<MyEntity> { 
    ... (and all other code like constructor and methods)... 
}
```

**Base Layer:**

```
export class BaseGrid<T> { 
    public async getData(): Promise<void> { ... }
}

... and 100 other functions
```

**Component specs:**

```
describe('MyComponent ', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyComponent],
            imports: [
                ...
        ],
            providers: [
            ],
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
    }));

    // here I created a reference function for my base class spec
    // Now, This is working but I don't want this **describe** and **it** to be here, 
    // it should be in the base file. so I can remove this repetitive code from all components.
    // And From here I just want to call one function let's say a **baseGridSpecs(component)**, 
    // that will load all the specs of base class in this component.
    describe('Should initialize Base grid', () => {
        it('should have proper component.', () => {
            const baseGridSpecs = new BaseGridSpecs<MyComponent>();
            baseGridSpecs.runBaseGridTests(component);
            baseGridSpecs.checkGetDataDefined(component);
        });
    });
});
```

**Base specs:**

```
export class BaseGridSpecs<T> {
  runBaseGridTests(component: any): void {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }

  checkGetDataDefined(component: any): void {
     expect(component.getData).toBeDefined();
  }
}
```

**This structure works fine for me,** but it has no use since my `describe` and `it` is still in main component spec file.

> What I am trying to achieve is to just call the base spec function like `baseGridSpecs.runBaseGridTests(component);` and it should render all `describe` and `it` specs for given generic component.

**Any help would be really appreciated...**

Comment: If all the subclasses should pass the same test suit that actually tests the logic of base class it seems that it is possible just run this suit once against base class and left only specific for subclasses tests in their suits. If the point is to ensure all the subclasses shares some behavior you could write a spec, list subclasses there and run the spec in a loop for each subclass.

Comment: @Shlang: yes, the motive is that all the sub classes should pass the same test suit that actually tests the logic of base class, but I am not able to create a specs inside base spec file. Basically I want all the specs in base file under one function, and when this function called from sub class with that component, it should return all the specs for that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasmine allows `it` definitions out of `describe` blocks and these definitions won't be run unless you call them explicitly from some `describe` block. [Official documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/sharing_behaviors) suggests two ways of using this fact.

The test subject can be shared with context but it requires you to use `function` instead of arrow functions and can be annoying and hard to track especially when there are many nested blocks, so your idea of having a class for specs makes sense.

Let's consider a simplified example with two classes. ([Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-galileo-vyi45?file=/src/test/base.spec.ts))

```
// Base.ts  
export class Base {
  baseMethod() {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

and

```
// Derived.ts
import { Base } from "./base";

export class Derived extends Base {
  derivedMethod() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Tests for Derived class that check Base class parts can be encapsulated in `BaseSpec`:

```
// base.spec.ts
export class BaseSpec {
  public component;

  checkComponentInitialized(): void {
    it("should have proper component", () => {
      expect(this.component).toBeTruthy();
    });
  }

  checkBaseMethodDefined(): void {
    it("should have baseMethod method", () => {
      expect(this.component.baseMethod).toBeDefined();
    });
  }

  itActsLikeABase(): void {
    this.checkComponentInitialized();
    this.checkBaseMethodDefined();
  }
}
```

This class then can be used elsewhere

```
// derived.spec.ts
import { Derived } from "./derived";
import { BaseSpec } from "./base.spec";

describe("Derived", () => {
  describe("as a Base", () => {
    const baseSpec = new BaseSpec();

    beforeEach(() => {
      baseSpec.component = new Derived();
    });

    baseSpec.itActsLikeABase();
  });

  describe("as a Derived", () => {
    let component;
    beforeEach(() => {
      component = new Derived();
    });

    it("should have derivedMethod method", () => {
      expect(component.derivedMethod).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

**Disclaimer**

While it is technically possible and may be appropriate in some cases please think twice before writing tests this way. Inheritance is a powerful but often misused tool. The duplication because of testing shared behavior is most likely an accidental duplication since tests should not depend on how the behavior is implemented. [Sharing behavior testing caveats](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/sharing_behaviors#caveats)

Comment: First of all thanks, I will surely try this and will keep you posted.

Comment: Briliant Shalang, it's working.Thank you. I will also post my answer once I make it as a way I wants.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of Shalang, I was able to add a unit tests in my base grid spec file.
Here is what I did.

**Component Specs:**

```
describe('MyComponent ', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [MyComponent],
          imports: [
              ...
      ],
          providers: [
          ],
      }).compileComponents().then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
      });
  }));

  describe('Should initialize Base grid', () => {
    const baseGridSpecs = new BaseGridSpecs<ComponentModel>();

    beforeEach(() => {
      baseGridSpecs.component = component;
      baseGridSpecs.fixture = fixture;          
    });

    // Here for me dummyData is model's object with proper value, 
    // which I can use to check service based calls.
    baseGridSpecs.loadSpecs(dummyData);
  });
});
```

**Base Specs:**

```
export class BaseGridSpecs<T> {
  public component;

  public fixture;

  loadSpecs(dummyData: any): void {
    describe('Should initialize base component with Proper methods', () => {
      it('should initialize properly.', () => {
        expect(this.component).toBeTruthy();
      });

      it('should have Base getData function defined.', () => {
        expect(this.component.getData).toBeDefined();
      });
    });
  }
}
```